# Center a percentage based div within a fullscreen div

Tags: css, html, margin, center

I know that margin-top in percentages are relative to the width... That's why, I can't always vertically and horizontally center a div that is 50% height, and 50% width of the full screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/

When you resize, the margin-top is relative to the width

CSS

```
#mini {
   height : 50%;
   width : 50%;
   background-color : #FFFFFF;
   margin-top : 25%;
   margin-left : 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/1/

## Code

```
#hello {
    position : absolute;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    background-color : #123456;
    text-align: center;
}
#hello:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#mini {
    height : 50%;
    width : 50%;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Based on http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

## How does it work?

- Horizontal centering (easy):

  ```
  #hello {
      text-align: center;
  }
  #mini {
      display: inline-block;
  }
  ```
- Vertical centering:

  1. Make line's height to be 100% height with a *ghost* element:

     ```
     #hello:before {
         content: '';
         display: inline-block;
         height: 100%;
         vertical-align: middle;
     }
     ```
  2. Center `#mini` vertically (relatively to that line) with `vertical-align`:

     ```
     #mini {
         display: inline-block;
         vertical-align: middle;
     }
     ```

## Browser support

Essentially everything and IE 8+.

You can support IE7 too if you use a real element as a *ghost*, instead of a `:before` pseudo element. But it isn't semantically correct.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the best approach: [**(live example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/aHng2/). It is supported in all modern browsers. [**Reference**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

Set the `html`/`body` elements to `height:100%` and `width:100%`.

Then set the display of the body, or the parent element to `table`.

Finally, use `display:table-cell`, and `vertical-align:middle` on the child element.

That will take care of the vertical alignment.

In order to center horizontally, set `margin:0px auto` on the child element.

In certain cases where the width of the child isn't defined or is dynamically generated, you can also use `text-align:center` assuming it is an `inline` element.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
body {
    display:table;
}

#parent {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:#123456;
}
#child {
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    background:white;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: @JHuangweb Thanks - it seems to be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure CSS workaround without relying on table layouts, or using inline-block elements. The trick is to position the `#mini` element absolutely within its parent halfway from the left and halfway from the top. After that, we offset the element itself by half of its own width and height by using CSS transform:

```
#mini {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/8BJ94/2/)

[CSS 2D transform is quite widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) among browsers today, with a global support of around 80%. You might want to include the `-ms-` vendor prefix if you want to support IE9 users, too.

Comment: Thanks you, that a very interesting solution. I'll choose another solution for support the maximum browsers, but it's interesting and very economic !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use some javascript. Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topMargin = $(window).height()*.25;
  $("#mini").css('margin-top', topMargin);
})

$(window).resize(function() {
  var topMargin = $(window).height()*.25;
  $("#mini").css('margin-top', topMargin);
})
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dphaener/2n4PL/

The first function sets the margin on page load, and the second sets it every time the window is resized.

Comment: Please don't use JavaScript to do things which can be done CSS only.

Comment: I would agree, but unfortunately I wasn't clever enough to come up with that nifty pure CSS solution.